# Applying knockout validation grouping to observablearray

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I'm trying to use group Knockout Validation on an observable array. I want to enable the submit button only when every array item validates successfully.

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Can anybody suggest if I'm close based on the below? I've removed code pertaining to other features of the UI for brevity and left only the code that's relevant.

I've also searched Stackoverflow for solutions but can't find one that addresses this specific issue.

Please advise. Thanks.

**Knockout**

```
    ko.validation.configure({
        registerExtenders: true,
        messagesOnModified: true,
        insertMessages: true,
        parseInputAttributes: true,
        messageTemplate: null,
        errorMessageClass: "input-notification error png_bg",
        grouping: {
            deep: true
        }
    });

    function Integer(integerValue) {
        this.integerValue = ko.observable(integerValue).extend({ number: true }).extend({ required: { message: 'Please enter an integer' } });
    }

    var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(integerList, options);

    viewModel.integers = ko.observableArray([
        new Integer("0"),
        new Integer("0")
    ]);

    viewModel.errors = ko.validation.group(viewModel.integerlists);

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

**HTML**

```
        <div data-bind="template: { name: 'integerTemplate', foreach: integers }"></div>
        <script id="integerTemplate" type="text/html">
            <input class="text-box single-line text-input large-input" type="number" data-bind="value: integerValue, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', css: { error: !integerValue.isValid() }" required />
        </script>
        <button class="large-input wide" data-bind="click: save, enable: errors().length == 0">Sort Integers</button>
```

Comment: It'd really be helpful if you created a JSFiddle example for us to play with.

Comment: Good idea. http://jsfiddle.net/hANm7/

Comment: Hey, the fiddle was not working, jsfiddle only accepts external resources from cdns. This one has correct external resources, but still some js errors: http://jsfiddle.net/z5935/2/ You should correct it and update the link.

Comment: Thank you pax162. http://jsfiddle.net/z5935/3/

Answer (score 0):

[Knockout Validation](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Custom-Validation-Rules)

If you are using this library, which it looks like you are, I'd suggest writing a custom validator (see single use validator)  and extend it onto you observableArray.

Inside of this custom validator you would just loop through and check if the array if valid (none of the values are null)

Comment: Thanks Matthew. I found an example: http://www.ideatoworking.com/Blogs/tabid/786/mctl/ArticleView/ModuleId/2042/articleId/13/Knockout-validation-for-2nd-level-of-array.aspx and here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bWJTY/19/. This behaves pretty much how I need but I'm struggling to apply it to my project. Hopefully somebody else can make use of it at least.

Comment: That link is dead, try : http://www.ideatoworking.com/Blogs/mctl/ArticleView/ModuleId/2042/articleId/13/Knockout-validation-for-2nd-level-of-array

Comment: Yeah, that's 404 now, too.